# How to Get A List Of All Attributes

Tags: attributes

How can I fetch a list (array) of all defined product attributes? (basically I need the code and label).

*edit*:

The attributes 
I need this to dynamically generate ACLs for all product attributes that exist in the shop. (working on a module for [Hide Attributes and Other Fields in Product Edit Backend](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3603/hide-attributes-and-other-fields-in-admin-backend))

Comment: Ignoring attribute sets?

Comment: @benmarks: Yes.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you need a MySQL Query, try that:

`select attribute_id, attribute_code, frontend_label from eav_attribute where entity_type_id IN (select entity_type_id from eav_entity_type where entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')`

An alternative to Fabian code, if you need a PHP script based on Magento, try this:

```
$attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')
    ->getItems();

foreach ($attributes as $attribute){
    echo $attribute->getAttributecode();
    echo '<br>';
    echo $attribute->getFrontendLabel();
}
```

Comment: Nice. `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Attribute_Collection` does basically what was Fabian trying to craft. Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome :-)

Comment: how do i get a list of attributes using a group id ? not attribute sets

Answer (score 5):

```
//Mage_Eav_Model_Mysql4_Entity_Attribute_Collection
Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')->setEntityTypeFilter(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY);
```

should do.

<strike>We just found a bug, you have to pass the entity_type_id:</strike>

```
$col = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')->setEntityTypeFilter(4);
```

**DOES**

## The code is the documentation:

```
if ($type instanceof Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Type) {
        $additionalTable = $type->getAdditionalAttributeTable();
        $id = $type->getId();
    } else {
        $additionalTable = $this->getResource()->getAdditionalAttributeTable($type);
        $id = $type;
    }
```

## <strike>hopefully</strike> working solution (updated by @Alex comment)

You have to pass a `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Type` so this should work and is not hardcoded:

```
$type = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type')->loadByCode(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY)
Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')->setEntityTypeFilter($type);
```

Comment: The collection returns a count of 0 ... I remember there was some kind of API or service class for this, but can't find it ATM.

Comment: Great - but 4 is hardcoded (even no sooo likely to change). Fix it for an upvote :-)

Comment: And no, the first line does not work. Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY is a string, not an Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Type

Comment: I think I got it now :D

Comment: But then I'm to late. I'll do, when I pass the 2k rep :p

Comment: I can help you. Help me too :-)

Comment: Actuall the way to find the typeID seems to be `        $entityTypeId = (int)Mage::getModel('eav/entity')->setType(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY)->getTypeId();` @see `\Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Attribute_Collection::_initSelect`

Comment: "hopefully working solution" is the working solution.

Answer (score 3):

This is to get all attributes

```
SELECT
    eav_attribute_option_value.option_id,
    eav_attribute_option_value.`value`,
    eav_attribute_option.attribute_id
                FROM
                        eav_attribute_option_value
                INNER JOIN eav_attribute_option ON eav_attribute_option_value.option_id = eav_attribute_option.option_id
                WHERE
                        eav_attribute_option.attribute_id = 135
                OR eav_attribute_option.attribute_id = 142 
                -- 135 = BRANDS
                -- 142 = TYPES
                GROUP BY
                        eav_attribute_option_value.option_id
                ORDER BY
                eav_attribute_option_value.`value` ASC
```

Comment: Don't want to use plain SQL ...

Comment: thats a good one, thanks