# List all EAV Attributes of an entity_type_id via SQL

Tags: sql, eav

How can I obtain the list of all EAV attributes of a specific entity (by its `entity_type_id`) via SQL?

Answer (score 4):

EAV attributes in the `eav_attribute` table are directly linked to the `entity_type` table. So all attributes can be revealed by a left-join query across those two tables:

```
-- show all eav attributes of an eav entity by entity_type_id

SET @entity_type_id = 10;

SELECT entity_type.entity_type_id, entity_type.entity_type_code
     , entity_type.entity_model
     , attribute.attribute_id, attribute.attribute_code, attribute.backend_type
    FROM eav_entity_type entity_type
    LEFT JOIN eav_attribute attribute 
        ON attribute.entity_type_id = entity_type.entity_type_id
    WHERE entity_type.entity_type_id = @entity_type_id;
```

Example output:

```
+----------------+------------------+-----------------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+
| entity_type_id | entity_type_code |     entity_model      | attribute_id | attribute_code | backend_type |
+----------------+------------------+-----------------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+
|             10 | mcd_comment      | mcd_meeting05/comment |          246 | comment        | text         |
|             10 | mcd_comment      | mcd_meeting05/comment |          249 | created_at     | static       |
|             10 | mcd_comment      | mcd_meeting05/comment |          245 | customer_id    | int          |
|             10 | mcd_comment      | mcd_meeting05/comment |          244 | guest_email    | varchar      |
|             10 | mcd_comment      | mcd_meeting05/comment |          243 | guest_name     | varchar      |
|             10 | mcd_comment      | mcd_meeting05/comment |          247 | page           | varchar      |
|             10 | mcd_comment      | mcd_meeting05/comment |          251 | product_id     | static       |
|             10 | mcd_comment      | mcd_meeting05/comment |          248 | store_id       | static       |
|             10 | mcd_comment      | mcd_meeting05/comment |          250 | updated_at     | static       |
+----------------+------------------+-----------------------+--------------+----------------+--------------+
```

Related non-SQL question:

- [How to Get A List Of All Attributes](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/3619/4115)

Answer (score 2):

**Please use bellow code**

```
    $entityTypeID = 'customer';  //customer,customer_address,catalog_category,catalog_product
    $entityType = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getEntityType($entityTypeID);
    $attributes = Mage::getResourceModel($entityType->getEntityAttributeCollection())
     ->getItems();
    foreach($attributes as $attribute) {
        print_r($attribute);
    }
```

**SQL**

```
select * from eav_attribute where entity_type_id IN (select entity_type_id from eav_entity_type where entity_type_code = 'customer')
```

Comment: I was concerned about a Q&A of SQL only. For Magento API PHP code I've referenced an existing question already. The subquery might be handy on quick first sight but lacks the possibility to obtain information from tha `eav_entity_type` table  IMHO.