# Show only necessary product information in backend for defined user group

Tags: product, attributes, event-observer, backend, user-roles

I'd like to update the products in my shop from various users who should only see the **absolutely needed input fields** so that no-one gets confused.

[image: Artikelinformationen in der Produktverwaltung]

The entries 'Webdesign' and 'Geschenkoptionen' should be hidden for users with usergroup 'Produktpflege' (Anm.: German for 'Product Maintenance').

After doing some reasearch it seem preferably to create an own extension.

I guess I found the right english Post already: [Hide Attributes and Other Fields in Product Edit Backend](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/3603/12447) Unfortunately I am new to this, this is why the Post does not explain enough for me. Right now I am not sure which extension should be extended and I don't know how I can assign it to certain users.

Could someone please give me a hint for my XML-files?

Big thanks in advance.

Comment: Nur english hier bitte.

Comment: Hi, das ist eine englischsprachige Community-Seite an der sich viele Magento Entwickler weltweit beteiligen. Bitte poste deine Frage auf Englisch - Danke! / Hi, this is a english-speaking community-page with magento developers around the world. Please post your question in English - Thanks!

Comment: This is a pretty complicated customization if done properly. We developed an extension for this, where you can configure exactly which user is able to edit which tab. If you are willing to pay for this, message me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found an extension which solved my problem:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/acl-product-attributes-tabs.html